# Signing out doesn't change wl_auth cookie value in onedrive?

Tags: javascript, cookies, onedrive

I followed the Javascript in [Interactive Live SDK](http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx?category=scenarioGroup_skyDrive&index=0) to enable Onedrive in My Web App and it's working fine.

But, following the above method sets a wl_auth cookie in the specified redirect domain. which contains the details of the user who was signed in during the time.

When I sign out the user and sign in with a different account the value of the old cookie still remains and I was only able to attach files from the old user not the new account. I have to follow the tedious process of deleting the cookies everytime to sign n a new user.

I have seen a Javascript method to subscribe to a logout event in Microsoft account. It is called [WL.Event.subscribe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550840.aspx). And I attach the following code to subscribe to a logout event,

```
WL.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", onLogout);

       function onLogout() {
         WL.logout();
        }
```

I try Logging out of my old account and logged in with different account . still the problem persists. why?

Any help is kindly appreciated. Thank you!

Note: I don't have signin button in my Web app. When the User clicks "Attach from Onedrive" button for the first time they will be asked for sign in information. if they are signed in already they  will be redirected to the Onedrive file Picker(till the cookie doesn't expire).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a custom signin button or are you using the signin button in WL.ui?  If you're using the WL.ui signin button, it should clear the cookies when the user clicks the sign out button.  The function that you provided above will only sign the user out after they have signed out.  You might want to change the event to "auth.statusChange" and call WL.getLoginStatus to see what it is returning.

Comment: I am not using WL.ui. I am using a custom button by clicking which the following code gets executed.   WL.init({ client_id: "<%=onedrive_client_id%>", redirect_uri: "/auth/onedrive/callback"});
                  WL.login({ "scope": "wl.skydrive wl.signin" }).then(
                    function(response) {
                        openFromSkyDrive();
                    }
                );

Comment: The user will get signin when he wants to attach a file and the value of cookie gets set. As per what you said If I use WL.ui instead of Wl.login will I be able to clear the cookies once the user gets signed out.

Comment: Toan I checked  **WL.getLoginStatus** after l logged out from my Microsoft Onedrive account and refreshing my app page, it still says connected. when I click "Attach from Onedrive" button in my app page it's opening file picker window as if it doesn't care about the SIGNOUT.

Comment: It does sound like the cookie isn't getting cleared but I can't seem to reproduce your problem.  Since you were using a custom sign-in button, it could be possible that you are not calling wl.logout, when the user presses the signout button (or something else is happening).  You will want your app to check the users status and display the necessary status on your button (i.e. signin, or signout) and call the necessary function (wl.login or wl.logout) based on the status.  If you use wl.ui, it will call wl.logout when the user presses the signout button so you shouldn't see the problem.

Comment: Ok!. I have 2 seperate web pages open. one my App where the user ataches files from onedrive(here, sign in options appear when user tries to attach a file and when the wl_auth cookie status=unknown ). the second web page is my Microsoft account where the user is logged in. even when they log out from their Microsoft account, they are still able to access Onedrive from my webapp as wl-auth still not cleared.

Comment: This problem is much like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/5e3e74dc-fa5a-4bfd-bb6f-a68841f9e20d/live-connect-api-leaves-wlauth-cookie-always-connected?forum=messengerconnec). But here also there is no solution found.

Comment: I cannot add wl.logout logic anywhere in my app because there is no way I can show signin/signout options in myapp

Comment: This is an interesting scenario since this would only affect users that have multiple accounts that they would like to use (with the same browser) with your app.  One thing that you can do, if you want to support this scenario, is to call WL.logout after your app has finished attaching the users files but the user would have to signin every time they want to attach a file.

Comment: yeah. you got it! thats my problem.